# If HTML maxlength is 110, why can I input 114 characters?

Tags: php, html, localization, maxlength

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" maxlength="110" />
```

You see, the maxlength is 110, but I was shocked when I found that I input 114 characters when I used

```
echo strlen($title);
```

Any idea?

By the way, what I input was **Japanese text**. What's wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Japanese text is most probably using a multibyte character encoding. Therefore you should make use of [mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 5):

> What's wrong?

PHP's string handling, which is based on the assumption that 1 character = 1 byte and leaves it to the programmer to tyke care of encodings everywhere and remember to use the more recent mb_* functions whenever dealing with strings that may use multibyte encodings.

Answer (score -2):

maxlength is just a browser lock but it's bypassable in any kind of way including by the unicode encoding.
You better provide a server side control for this

Comment: You make this sound like a hack, which it isn't. This is a bug in PHP's strlen().

Comment: It's an anti-hack.What happen if i open the site and with fiebug i change the maxlenght to 99999999 ?

Comment: It's no hack. It is just for convenience of the user, not for security.
If you limit the character-count on the client side it can only be to save the user from reentering shorter information after the server rejects the too long input.
You must not trust the information submitted from the user-side.